# How might we convert type declarations into constructor calls?

Tags: compilers, interpreters, object-oriented

Suppose that we have two languages, **A** and **B**.

In language **A**, there are a *lot* of data-type declarations.

In language **B** there are no data-type declarations to the left of the assignment operator, but constructor calls do exist.

How would you recommend converting the type declarations into constructor calls?

| Input | Output |
| --- | --- |
| `int x = lstring.numel()` | `x = int(lstring.numel())` |
| `string final_msg = concat(err_msg, trace_str)` | `final_msg = string(concat(err_msg, trace_str))` |

That is, the data type, such as `int` or `string`, has to be moved from the left-hand side of `=` over to the right-hand side and we have to insert some parentheses.

Comment: What sort of recommendation are you looking for here? Some sort of syntax rewriting system? `sed -e 's/^\([^ ]*\) \([^=]*\)=\(\s*\)\(.*\)$/\2= \1(\4)/'`?  A language-level feature in A or B?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense, the input and output are doing fundamentally different things. On the left you have a compiler _checking_ that your assignment is valid, based on additional _metadata_ of the expected type; it will compile because `lstring.numel()` returns `int`-compatible (assuming it does). On the right, under the same assumption, `x = lstring.numel()` is already assigning an integer to `x`, so wrapping it in an `int` call isn't needed. Likewise if `concat` returns a string. _(Given it looks like Python, the actual equivalent is e.g. `x: int = lstring.numel()`.)_

Comment: In other words, the difference between statically- and dynamically-typed languages is larger than just moving a word around and adding some parentheses.

Comment: This question isn't entirely non-sensical, because statically-typed languages do not only check the type of the right-hand-side; they also coerce it, or otherwise can have specific rules for literals in certain contexts. For example, `double x = 5;` coerces `5` to `5.0` in Java, and `byte x = 5;` contextually treats `5` as a byte literal rather than an int literal (this is different to coercion, and only applies to literals). When translating to another language, therefore, you might need to call a function to perform the conversion which is contextually implied in Java.

Comment: That said, this is still a strange question because you are asking about translating *only* this, as if there aren't other differences between the two languages. In reality when transpiling from one language to another you most likely need an [intermediate representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_representation), which could be an AST including nodes for "invisible" operations such as coercions, so that explicit code can be emitted for those operations where required in the target language. So the answer depends heavily on your IR, but the question gives no details about it.

Answer (score 0):

For the examples provided, detecting declarations with regular expressions is possible, and creating their replacements by substitution. [sed](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) is made for that and

```
sed -e 's/^\([^ ]*\)\s*\([^ =][^=]*\)=\(\s*\)\(.*\)$/\2=\3\1(\4)/' code.langA
```

will find any complete single line with the form `<single-word> <anything-but-=> = <anything-at-all>` (matched using a standard [POSIX basic regular expression](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03)) and shift the first word across, parenthesising whatever is on the right-hand side too. Lines that don't have that format will be unchanged.

sed ("stream editor") is a standard Unix command available on all Unix-likes, including macOS, and via WSL or Cygwin on Windows. Other tools and editors with regular-expression-based find-and-replace will be able to perform similar transformations too, likely with slightly different expression syntax.

---

While standard sed doesn't include it, many common versions have a `-i` mode for in-place updating of files. With those implementations,

```
sed -i.bak 's/^\([^ ]*\)\s*\([^ =][^=]*\)=\(\s*\)\(.*\)$/\2=\3\1(\4)/' *.langA
```

will fix every langA file at once where they are. If you have many files this will be more convenient. For more complex scenarios, you can ask on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) for further guidance.

---

In general, a regular expression is not able to match all valid cases (or not able to avoid matching some invalid cases) in a typical programming language syntax. Language A may not have any of those cases, or they may just not come up in the code you're operating on, and then there's no issue. Many real-world codebases will be in this safe space in practice.

For maximum reliability, or for dealing with unknown or inconsistent code, you'd need a real parser specifically for language A. That parser would need to preserve enough source information to reconstruct the input (e.g. the kind of parser & syntax tree used for pretty-printing), and then it could be used to reproduce the input exactly with that small transformation made.

This will be more correct but may be significantly more work, and potentially not worthwhile if this is a one-off translation where errors will be easily detected for manual correction. For a repeated, automated, fragile, or unattended process, it will be essential. A real-world instance of a similar system is Python's [2to3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html) migration tool, which made various minor rewrites on top of a full Python 2 parser.